# How to Convert CString to VT_ARRAY|VT_UI1

Tags: c++, mfc, atl

I've inherited an old application which makes use of the CppWebBrowser control.
The application has always used the ::Navigate method for GET requests but now I have a need to start using it for a POST; however, the existing code does not work for a POST. I have limited knowledge working with these data types but I suspect it has to do with the CString to VT_ARRAY|VT_UI1 conversion.

```
void WebPostData(TCppWebBrowser *CppWebBrowser, CString sURL, CString sPostData)
{
    BSTR bstrHeaders = NULL;
    TVariant vFlags = { 0 }, vTargetFrameName = { 0 }, vPostData = { 0 }, vHeaders = { 0 };
    LPSAFEARRAY psa;
    LPCTSTR cszPostData = sPostData;
    UINT cElems = lstrlen(cszPostData);
    LPSTR pPostData;
    LPVARIANT pvPostData;

        bstrHeaders = SysAllocString(L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencodedrn");
        if (!bstrHeaders){
            Application->MessageBox("Could not allocate bstrHeaders", "Warning", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
            return;
        }

        V_VT(&vHeaders) = VT_BSTR;
        V_BSTR(&vHeaders) = bstrHeaders;

        pvPostData = vPostData;

        if (pvPostData){
            VariantInit(pvPostData);

            psa = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UI1, 0, cElems);
            if (!psa){
                return;
            }

            SafeArrayAccessData(psa, (LPVOID*)&pPostData);
            memcpy(pPostData, cszPostData, cElems);
            SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);

            V_VT(pvPostData) = VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1;
            V_ARRAY(pvPostData) = psa;
        }

        CppWebBrowser->Navigate((TVariant)sURL, &vFlags, &vTargetFrameName, &vPostData, &vHeaders);
}
```

Comment: Does [**this**](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27519) help?

Comment: I suppose you have a Unicode build (might be not, esp. that it's legacy project), in which case `CString` value would be Unicode string, and you want ASCII or UTF-8 for `memcpy`ing into byte array.

Comment: That article looks like the exact place where the original developer copied the code from, except they changed the sPostData parameter from a String to a CString.  Also, some of the comments about that article state that it didn't work for posts.

Answer (score 1):

The code you showed was copied from this C++Builder example:

[How to post data using TCppWebBrowser in C++Builder](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27519)

`CString` is an MFC class, but C++Builder does not support MFC.  The original code used a `System::String` instead, which is a C++Builder class.  So, are you trying to convert this code to Visual Studio?  Or are you really using C++Builder?  You did not say.

I am going to assume you are using C++Builder, otherwise you have to re-write the code for Visual Studio classes.

So, let's first and foremost change `CString` back to `String`.  Now, depending on which version of C++Builder you are using, `String` is either **ANSI** (C++Builder 3-2007) or **UTF-16** (C++Builder 2009+).  There is a `_DELPHI_STRING_UNICODE` precompiler define in the latter case.

The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` type is not typically sent as UTF-16, and there is no guarantee that the web server will be able to handle it.  So I suggest you convert the `sPostData` data to UTF-8, then you can create a VT_UI1 array of the UTF-8 bytes:

```
#ifndef _DELPHI_STRING_UNICODE
inline bool NeedsUTF8(String s)
{
    // String is 1-indexed
    for (int i = 1; i <= s.Length(); ++i)
    {
        int ch = s[i];
        if (ch > 0x7F) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
#endif

void WebPostData(TCppWebBrowser *CppWebBrowser, String sURL, String sPostData)
{
    TVariant vFlags, vTargetFrameName, vPostData, vHeaders;

    // note: UTF8String was added in C++Builder 6,
    // use AnsiString in C++Builder 3-5 instead
    UTF8String utf8;

    #ifdef _DELPHI_STRING_UNICODE
    // C++Builder 2009+, convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 directly
    utf8 = sPostData;
    #else
    // C++Builder 3-2007, check if ASCII or ANSI
    if (NeedsUTF8(sPostData))
    {
        // ANSI, so convert from ANSI to UTF-16 to UTF-8,
        // but you have to do the last step manually
        WideString wPostData(sPostData);
        int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, wPostData.c_bstr(), wPostData.Length(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
        utf8.SetLength(len);
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, wPostData.c_bstr(), wPostData.Length(), utf8.c_str(), len, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        // ASCII, compatible with UTF-8 as-is
        utf8 = sPostData;
    }
    #endif

    LPSAFEARRAY psa = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UI1, 0, utf8.Length());
    if (!psa)
        return;

    // TVariant takes ownership of a safearray
    vPostData = psa;

    // TVariant takes ownership of a copy of a WideString's BSTR
    vHeaders = WideString("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8\r\n");

    LPVOID pPostData;
    if (FAILED(SafeArrayAccessData(psa, &pPostData)))
        return;

    memcpy(pPostData, utf8.c_str(), utf8.Length());
    SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);

    CppWebBrowser->Navigate((TVariant)sURL, &vFlags, &vTargetFrameName, &vPostData, &vHeaders);
}
```